# How to display input boxes while clicking popover?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I need to have 3 input boxes with contents as shown in fig

[image]

I have used bootstrap popover to display the content as follows,

```
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-container="body" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="bottom" data-content="Vivamus
  sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus.">
    Select your Room
  </button>
```

I am unable to display the boxes as shown inside data-content, or otherwise any alternative solution that solves my issue would be helpful..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(function() {
  $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover()
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-container="body" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="bottom" data-html="true" data-content='<button type="button" class="btn">Button 1</button><button type="button" class="btn">Button 2</button><button type="button" class="btn">Button 3</button>'>Select
your Room
</button>
```

If you simply want to add html content to the popover, just set the attribute `html="true"` and pass some html in the `data-content`.

In your example it would be:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-container="body" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="bottom" data-html="true" data-content='<button type="button" class="btn">Button 1</button><button type="button" class="btn">Button 2</button><button type="button" class="btn">Button 3</button>'>
    Select your Room
</button>
```

Example here: https://jsfiddle.net/r37jf4qm/

Popover options are documented [here](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#popovers-options).

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for. You can always change the styling.

```css
/**
 * CSS Toggle with no inputs
 */
* { margin: 0; padding: 0; box-sizing: border-box;}
html{
 background: #f06;
 background: linear-gradient(45deg, #f06, yellow);
 min-height: 100%;
 font: 1.5em/1.13 Verdana, sans-serif;
}
.ctrl {
 position:absolute;
 top: 50%; left: 50%;
 transition: .5s;
}
.button, .tip a {
 display: block;
 opacity: .56; filter: alpha(opacity=56); /* For IE8 and earlier */
 background: #c9c9c9;
 color: #7a8092;
 text-align: center;
 text-decoration: none;
 text-shadow: 0 -1px dimgrey;
}
.button:hover, .ctrl a:hover, .button:focus, .ctrl a:focus { opacity: 1; filter: alpha(opacity=100); /* For IE8 and earlier */}
.button:focus, .ctrl a:focus { outline: none; }
.button {
 z-index: 2;
 margin: -.625em;
 width: 1.25em; height: 1.25em;
 border-radius: 50%;
 box-shadow: 0 0 3px 1px white;
}
/* circular menu */
.tip {
 z-index: 1;
 /**outline: dotted 1px white;/**/
 margin: -5em;
 width: 10em; height: 10em;
 transform: scale(.001);
 list-style: none;
 opacity: 0;
}
/* the ends of the menu */
.tip:before, .tip:after {
 position: absolute;
 top: 34.3%;
 width: .5em; height: 14%;
 opacity: .56;
 background: #c9c9c9;
 content: '';
}
.tip:before {
 left: 5.4%;
 border-radius: .25em 0 0 .25em;
 box-shadow: -1px 0 1px dimgrey, inset 1px 0 1px white, inset -1px 0 1px grey, 
    inset 0 1px 1px white, inset 0 -1px 1px white;
 transform: rotate(-75deg);
}
.tip:after {
 right: 5.4%;
 border-radius: 0 .25em .25em 0;
 box-shadow: 1px 0 1px dimgrey, inset -1px 0 1px white, inset 1px 0 1px grey,
    inset 0 1px 1px white, inset 0 -1px 1px white;
 transform: rotate(75deg);
}
/* make the menu appear on click */
.button:focus + .tip {
 transform: scale(1);
 opacity: 1;
}
/* slices of the circular menu */
.slice {
 overflow: hidden;
 position: absolute;
 /**outline: dotted 1px yellow;/**/
 width: 50%; height: 50%;
 transform-origin: 100% 100%;
}
/* 
 * rotate each slice at the right angle = (A/2)° + (k - (n+1)/2)*A°
 * where A is the angle of 1 slice (30° in this case)
 * k is the number of the slice (in {1,2,3,4,5} here)
 * and n is the number of slices (5 in this case)
 * formula works for odd number of slices (n odd)
 * for even number of slices (n even) the rotation angle is (k - n/2)*A°
 * 
 * after rotating, skew on Y by 90°-A°; here A° = the angle for 1 slice = 30° 
 */
.slice:first-child { transform: rotate(-45deg) skewY(60deg); }
.slice:nth-child(2) { transform: rotate(-15deg) skewY(60deg); }
.slice:nth-child(3) { transform: rotate(15deg) skewY(60deg); }
.slice:nth-child(4) { transform: rotate(45deg) skewY(60deg); }
.slice:last-child { transform: rotate(75deg) skewY(60deg); }
/* covers for the inner part of the links so there's no hover trigger between
   star button & menu links; give them a red background to see them */
.slice:after {
 position: absolute;
 top: 32%; left: 32%;
 width: 136%; height: 136%;
 border-radius: 50%;
 /* "unskew" = skew by minus the same angle by which parent was skewed */
 transform: skewY(-60deg);
 content: '';
}
/* menu links */
.slice a {
 width: 200%; height: 200%;
 border-radius: 50%;
 box-shadow: 0 0 3px dimgrey, inset 0 0 4px white;
 /* "unskew" & rotate by -A°/2 */
 transform: skewY(-60deg) rotate(-15deg);
 background: /* lateral separators */
   linear-gradient(75deg, 
  transparent 50%, grey 50%, transparent 54%) no-repeat 36.5% 0,
   linear-gradient(-75deg, 
  transparent 50%, grey 50%, transparent 54%) no-repeat 63.5% 0,
  /* make sure inner part is transparent */
  radial-gradient(rgba(127,127,127,0) 49%, 
     rgba(255,255,255,.7) 51%, #c9c9c9 52%);
 background-size: 15% 15%, 15% 15%, cover;
 line-height: 1.4;
}
/* arrow for middle link */
.slice:nth-child(3) a:after {
 position: absolute;
 top: 13%; left: 50%;
 margin: -.25em;
 width: .5em; height: .5em;
 box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px white;
 transform: rotate(45deg);
 background: linear-gradient(-45deg, #c9c9c9 50%, transparent 50%);
 content: '';
}
```

```html
<a class='button ctrl' href='#' tabindex='1'>★</a>
<ul class='tip ctrl'>
 <li class='slice'><a href='#'>✦</a></li>
 <li class='slice'><a href='#'>✿</a></li>
 <li class='slice'><a href='#'>✵</a></li>
 <li class='slice'><a href='#'>✪</a></li>
 <li class='slice'><a href='#'>☀</a></li>
</ul>
```

credit: https://codepen.io/vavik96